# Android x86 on PC black screen error

Tags: windows, android-x86

I have just installed Android 7.1 (from Android x86 project) on my PC and have encountered an error.

I have Windows 10 as main OS and Android 7.1 as secondary. I was trying to create dual boot.

When I boot up the PC, I get the grub menu and select default
android option from menu (the one which ws alrady selected). It starts to boot up and a screen with some text pops up for a second then it moves to a black screen with a blinking underscore in the top left corner. I have then reinstalled it and selected the video debug option at which point it does boot and works correctly, however as soon as I restart the computer, the error occurs again regardless of which option I
select.

*My PC specs*

Intel Core 2 Duo E7300 2.99ghz with
4 GB RAM.